# utf8::all -- How to force <STDIN/OUT> to big-5

Tags: perl, utf-8

This is my test code:
I am using win32 strawberry perl.

> use utf8::all; my $input =  ;

when key in a Chinese character,

it shows the error:

```
utf8 "\xAD" does not map to unicode .....
```

I have also write a script with utf8::all to print Chinese characters, can't success.
If just use utf8 or without utf8, I can print Chinese characters by encoding them.

How to set the  to other encoding?

Answer (score 6):

> How to set the to other encoding?

With `utf8::all`, you can't. The encoding `UTF-8` is hardcoded everywhere in it. The module is named, after all, `utf8::all` and not `big5::all`.

You must decode/encode **explicitely**, see http://p3rl.org/UNI. You said you're on Windows, so employ the encoding [`cp950`](http://p3rl.org/Encode%3a%3aTW).

```
use Encode qw(decode encode);

my @arguments_as_characters = decode 'cp950', @ARGV;
open my $file_handle, '<:encoding(cp950)', $file_name;
print encode 'cp950', $data_to_stdout;
```

---

---

> How to open STDIN, STDOUT in cp950?

When you run your program, the standard streams *are* already open! You can modify the [I/O layer](http://p3rl.org/PerlIO%3a%3aencoding) with [`binmode`](http://p3rl.org/binmode).

```
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(cp950)';
```

Comment: How to open STDIN, STDOUT in cp950?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround to set the codepage of Windows Command Prompt to UTF-8, but it's not a deploy-able solution.

My suggestion is don't bother, just use Big5 all the way in Perl (and stick to CP950/zh-tw Windows), or use text file I/O for input/output.

Or, to be adventurous, use bash/perl within cgywin that use UTF-8 out of box instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
use open IO => ':encoding(big5)';
```

or

```
use open IO => ':encoding(cp950)';
```

or

```
use open IO => ':locale';
```